# How do you use Binary conversion in Python/Bash/AWK?

Tags: python, bash, binary, awk

I am new in binary conversion.
I use Python, Bash and AWK daily.

I would like to see binary conversion's applications in these languages.
For example, I am interested in problems which you solve by it at your work.

**Where do you use binary conversion in Python/Bash/AWK?**

I would like to see examples of codes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What sort of binary conversion are you talking about?

Comment: Binary conversion of what data?  Why?

Comment: @S.Lott: One winner at Topcoder says that he uses Binary conversion daily with algorithms.

Comment: @Brian: I mean to convert Dec numbers to binary numbers.

Comment: @NewbieQuestions that sounds like a misquote, "binary conversion" has little to nothing to do with algorithms.  You might want to track down what he/she actually said.  Or ask the person who said it to clarify what the meant.

Comment: see also: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Non-decimal_radices/Convert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conversion of strings of binary digits to a number using Python on the commandline:

```
binary=00001111
DECIMAL=$(python -c "print int('$BINARY', 2)")
echo $decimal
```

See the docs for the [int function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#int).

Oh, wait, I misread the question, you want to know what converting to binary gets you.  Well, that depends on what you mean by "convert to binary".  Say I want to store a file with a million integers.  The integers will be between 0 and 32,000.  If I were to store them as text it would take at best two bytes for each number (single digit number and a separator), at worst six bytes (five digit number and a separator), with an average size of 4.6 bytes per number (see comment for the math).  I also would have no easy way of choosing the 15th number.  If I were store them as 16bit integers (in binary), every number would take up exactly two bytes and I could find the 15th number by `seek`'ing to offset `2*(15-1)` and reading two bytes.  Also, when I go to do math on the text based version I (or my language) must first convert the string to a number, whereas the binary version is already a 16bit number.

So, in short, you use binary types to

1. save space
2. have consistent record sizes
3. speed up programs

Comment: @Owens: Do you use binary conversion daily?

Comment: Again, it depends on what you mean by "binary conversion".  In some jobs many of the data files were binary files for the reasons listed above.

Comment: you have 10 1-digit, 90 2-digit, 900 3-digit, 9000 4-digit and 23000 5-digit numbers so your "average" is really 4.6

Answer (score 2):

In shell, a nice use of [`dc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750606/what-technologies-are-you-using-even-though-they-are-embarassingly-out-of-date/750620#750620):

```
echo 2i 00001111 pq | dc
```

2i means: *base for input numbers is 2*.

pq means: *print and quit*.

The other way is:

```
echo 2o 15 pq | dc
```

I don't remember having used this feature in real-world situations.

Comment: @mouviciel: One Winner of a Topcoder competition said to me that he have to use binary conversion daily with algorihtms. Can that be true?

Comment: Maybe for him... The rare occasions when I need to convert to and from binary is when I code close to the hardware.

Comment: No point in using echo and a pipe, save a process and just use dc -e '2i 00001111 pq'.

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of Python there exists the `bin()` function which I believe takes an int and returns a binary literal, of form `0b011010` or whatever.